Resizing of svg leads to additional height
I have an interactive svg and tried to make it responsive with viewbox and display: flex:
// HTML
<div className="interactive-svg">
  <svg ref={svgRef} viewBox={`0 0 ${svgWidth} ${svgHeight}`} />
</div>



// CSS-Styles
.interactive-svg {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  svg {
    user-select: none;
    cursor: cell;
  }
}

But if I shrink the windowsize the svg seems to gain height that should not be there:

If I inspect the element I see that it automatically sets a height and width. If I remove it in the inspector the desired effect occurs:

How to specify that in HTML/CSS to get the desired effect meaning that the "rectangular"-svg preserves
Is it because of flex?

are you looking for preserveAspectRatio="none"

No this would distort the elements inside the svg (e.g. if you minimize the svg the circles would be "squashed" etc.). Though is hinders the effect of the "additional height"

The desired effect can be seen in the second gif.
The svg in the inspection was : <svg ref={svgRef} viewBox={`0 0 1200 600`} "width="1200" height="600" /> which lead to additional height. After removing width="1200" height="600" this additional height went away. How to get this property in HTML/CSS?

so what do you want to happen? preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" or something else i.e. how do you want a rectangle that's not the same aspect ratio as the outer rectangle to be fitted inside it? Normally you wouldn't want a viewBox that changes. Without seeing the SVG content it's hard to know what you're trying to do. Please post text as text and not as images. I can't actually read any of the text in the images.

If you don't want height and width attributes then don't add them.

They are added automatically. Inside my code I only have <svg ref={svgRef} viewBox={`0 0 ${svgWidth} ${svgHeight}`}

Added automatically by what? The browser won't add them by itself.

I do not know thats why I ask. Do you mean it is not because of the viewbox or flex?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Flexbox is the reason you need to (re)set width and height explicitly for child svg:
.interactive-svg svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: cell;
}


Yes I just got an similar idea (but with fixed max-width). Thank you!
